# How to patch services.jar on Android 5?

Tags: java, android, jar

I want to patch services.jar because I want to edit the high-end OOM level limits because my tablet is always having 300+ MB of RAM free which is making multitasking hard because the tablet only have 1GB of RAM installed.

This is the checklist:

1. I extracted the classes.dex from services.jar
2. I found what values have to change and I changed them using a hex editor
3. I recalculated a checksum of classes.dex (Adler32 and SHA-1)
4. I packed the classes.dex in to the services.jar
5. **??? What else should I do?** (I'm afraid that I missed something and that I may brick my tablet)

Also note that my tablet ROM is odex free so I can patch services.jar.
Also I have a root rights.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checklist is sufficient. I tried patched services.jar on my tablet and it work like a charm.